# How do you set up selenium tests to run nightly, and where do you store the files?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, python

I understand this question may look subjective, so I will do my best to make this more specific.

I have created a suite of Selenium TestCases using Python. I want these tests to run each night, against a particular URL.

Where is the best place to store a large number of Selenium tests? And are there any tools which I can use to manage these tests, so that they run each evening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Where is the best place to store a large number of Selenium tests?

The ideal place for your selenium tests would be a **source code repository**, like `git` or `mercurial`.

You don't have to host the repository yourself and can use third-party services, code hosting solutions like [`github`](https://github.com/) or [`bitbucket`](https://bitbucket.org/product).

> And are there any tools which I can use to manage these tests, so that they run each evening?

The ideal place to run these tests would be a **continuous integration (CI) server**, which will aside from *scheduling*, solve the test result *reporting* problem, *notifications* etc. There is a number of available CI tools, like `Jenkins` or `Bamboo`.

There are also modern CI and delivery third-party services like [`Travis CI`](https://travis-ci.org/) or [`Circle CI`](https://circleci.com/).

Also look into cross-browser and cross-platform services like [`Browser Stack`](https://www.browserstack.com/) and [`Sauce Labs`](https://saucelabs.com/). They may act as a *remote selenium server* for your tests.

Answer (score 4):

> Where is the best place to store a large number of Selenium tests?

In the project which they are testing. Always version control tests with the production code, or you will have a lot of extra pain for no gain.

> [A]re there any tools which I can use to manage these tests, so that they run each evening?

A crontab or Jenkins timed job will do the trick, but I would very much advise to configure it to run your tests on every *commit* rather than every night.

Answer (score 1):

**Where to store tests:** You use source code repository, do you? They are free.

**How to run them:** It depends how you designed the test suite - I assume to use some standard test runner?

We have great success with Jenkins as test runner. You can set up dependencies (run some group of test only if another group succeeded), and you see the run history and tendencies.

Comment: I actually don't use a source code repository, I store them on a shared drive, as I'm the only one writing them. And while I do use PyUnit to run the test suites, I still have to manually run it. I was looking for something a bit more high level to manage that for me. I guess a CI server is the way to go!

Comment: Before any CI server, get version control.